# specific argument was out of range of valid value parameter name : index

Tags: c#, tcpclient

Error : specific argument was out of range of valid value parameter name : index

This error message occurred every 2min in design time!!

what should i do?

Comment: You should provide more code.

Comment: i don't know i should provide which part of my code. this error occurred when i open my project. and the project have so many classes, forms, and 8 projects.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The designer executes code from controls on the design surface at design time.  This error is probably coming from code in one of your UserControls, or possibly a buggy third party control.

Things you can do to help prevent code being executed at Design Time:

- Avoid putting such code in the constructor of your UserControl.
- Use `if (this.DesignMode)` to conditionally suppress the code at design-time.  It's common to do this in the `OnLoad` method.
- Mark properties in your usercontrol that should not be evaluated at design-time with appropriate attributes, e.g.:

  ```
  [
  Browsable(false),
  DesignerSerializationVisibility(DesignerSerializationVisibility.Hidden)
  ]
  public MyType MyRuntimeOnlyProperty
  {
      ...
  }
  ```

If all else fails, you can start a second instance of Visual Studio, and attach its debugger to your instance that's running the Designer.  Then break on the appropriate exception.